# Keeping Specific Webpage from Grouping With other IE Windows

Tags: taskbar, internet-explorer-11

I have a webpage that I use all day throughout work, that I switch back and forth to quite frequently. I would like to know if it's possible to keep the icon separate from the rest of my IE windows in the task bar. Not sure if this could be done via a command line switch or not.

Again, I **do** want to keep groupings on my other IE windows/tabs as normal - just would like to keep this other one separate, preferably by a command line switch if possible (I have no administrator privileges - so other workaround would be acceptable as long as it does not require an elevated action).

I use IE 11 and run Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible with IE, but with Chrome, if you create multiple user profiles, each profile's taskbar icon forms a separate group.

See this screenshot - I have two Chrome windows open under each profile.
[image: A Windows 7 taskbar with two separate groups of Chrome icons. There is another application in between them.]

There is one drawback to this - on Windows 7, unlike IE, Chrome does not provide a thumbnail preview for each tab within a given window when you mouse over the taskbar icon. In the screenshot, the third Chrome window (the one open to this question) has 9 tabs open, but only one thumbnail preview is offered - that of the most-recently-active tab in each window.

Comment: Another (very minor) drawback I've recently discovered: "Pin to taskbar" doesn't work properly with multiple Chrome profiles. If you have windows for both profiles open, you can individually pin them both, but if you close them both and then try to use the pinned icons to open them, each will wind up opening a window for the same Chrome profile (not yet sure of the determining factor for which profile that will be).

Comment: BTW, the Chrome dev team has fixed the "Pin to taskbar" issue with multiple profiles since my prior comment.